# How to release UITabBarController with all its view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I programmatically create a tab bar with two view controllers like the following code. I find it hard to clean the memory when I do not need the tab bar any more. Apple's documentation is very limited about releasing tab bar controller. I don't know how to release all the view controllers in the 'viewControllers' array. I tried to print out the retain count and found x & y's retainCount is as high as 5.

```
@interface X:UIViewController
@interface Y:UIViewController

@interface Z: UIViewController {
  UITabBarController *tabBar; 
}
@end

@implementation Z
-(IBAction)openTabBarUp{
  UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

  X *x = [[X alloc] init];
  Y *y = [[Y alloc] init];

  tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: x, y, nil];
  [self.view addSubView: tabBar.view];

}
```

this is how I try to release the memory:

```
-(IBAction)removeTabBar{
  [tabBar.view removeFromSuperView];
  [tabBar release];
  tabBar = nil;
}
```

Thanks

Leo

Comment: The absolute retainCount of an object is meaningless.  You are wasting your time thinking about it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)openTabBarUp{
  tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

  X *x = [[X alloc] init];
  Y *y = [[Y alloc] init];

  tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: x, y, nil];
  [self.view addSubView: tabBar.view];

}
```

You done need `UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];` in the `openTabBarUp` method as you already have an instance of it declared in the header file. You can release the tabBar using `[tabBar release];` but Apple insists to add the tabBarController as the rootview of your main window and not as part of any view controller.

**UPDATE**

The [Apple reference documents on `UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the
>   root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar
>   interface should never be installed as a child of another view
>   controller.

Comment: I see. I think that's why I get weird retain counts. Thanks a lot. I'll need to think alternative to UITabBar

Comment: You get weird retain counts because you looked at the retain count!  Seriously -- the absolute retain count of an object is meaningless.